# What is the difference between `poetry run black myscript.py` and `black myscript.py`?

Tags: python, python-poetry, python-black

Based on the [poetry docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#using-poetry-run):

> Likewise if you have command line tools such as `pytest` or `black` you
> can run them using `poetry run pytest`

The suggested way to use [black](https://github.com/psf/black) is:

```
poetry run black myscript.py
```

However, I do not notice any difference in behaviour if I just use

```
black myscript.py
```

**What is the difference between these two methods?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It allows you to run `black` (or whichever command comes after `run`)  installed in your virtual environment *without needing to activate your virtual environment first*.

The relevant note is in the [`poetry run` docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#run) (emphasis mine):

> The `run` command executes the given command **inside the project’s virtualenv**.

Let's say you have this **poetry-demo** project with a **main.py**, and you installed `black`:

```
poetry-demo$ ls
README.rst     main.py        poetry.lock    poetry_demo    pyproject.toml tests

poetry-demo$ poetry add black
The following packages are already present in the pyproject.toml and will be skipped:

  • black

...
```

If you don't activate your virtual environment first (i.e. `poetry shell`) and *if you have no `black` installed anywhere else on your system*, simply doing `black file.py` would fail:

```
poetry-demo$ which black

poetry-demo$ black main.py
-bash: black: command not found
```

But, with `poetry run`, even without activating your virtual environment, you can run `black`:

```
poetry-demo$ poetry run black main.py
All done! ✨  ✨
1 file left unchanged.
```

The source of your confusion is probably because you already have your virtual environment activated, so then there really is no difference:

```
poetry-demo$ poetry shell
Spawning shell within /path/to/virtualenvs/poetry-demo-hCA44HQ0-py3.8
poetry-demo$ . /path/to/virtualenvs/poetry-demo-hCA44HQ0-py3.8/bin/activate

(poetry-demo-hCA44HQ0-py3.8) poetry-demo$ black main.py
All done! ✨  ✨
1 file left unchanged.

(poetry-demo-hCA44HQ0-py3.8) poetry-demo$ poetry run black main.py
All done! ✨  ✨
1 file left unchanged.
```